# Differences in file i/o between delphi6 and rad2010 on windows8-10

Tags: file, windows-8, url-rewriting, privileges

I have a piece of code basically copy-pasted from delphi6 to rad2010 application, however, there seems to be a difference in the way i/o functions work (on windows 8+ only). My programs create a new file (using rewrite, filemode, close, etc, nothing fancy) in the "c:\programdata" folder (actually the one read from registry's "common appdata"). The delphi6 application creates the file and is able to write to it again. Such file features normal delete when right-clicked in windows explorer. Rad2010-application-created-file, however, features administrator's icon on the delete, and the same application is unable to open it for writing next time it's called. Is this possible to fix with minimal code corrections so i can employ my stone age codes or do i have to study manifests and other modern stuff? Please as brief as possible and no why's. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously an OS issue (my rad2010 app even works when called on a win10 computer from a win7 computer over the network). The solution is to use api's createfile function (instead of rewrite) with all access rights 1st parameter ($1FF), eg `createfile(filename,$1FF,0,nil,2,128,0)`